# Run AppleScript from bash script

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, bash, command-line

If I wanted to run an AppleScript from within a bash script I could call a file with the list of commands that I require to execute.

```
#!/bin/bash
{some commands}
osascript file.scpt
{other commands}
```

What, however, if I wanted to run commands that needed to be run in sequence from within bash?

An example would be

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
echo This will open Google Chrome in Kiosk mode
  osascript -e "tell application \"Google Chrome\""
  osascript -e "activate"
  osascript -e     "tell application \"System Events\""
  osascript -e         "key down {command}"
  osascript -e         "key down {shift}"
  osascript -e         "keystroke \"f\""
  osascript -e         "key up {shift}"
  osascript -e         "key up {command}"
  osascript -e     "end tell"
echo "Google Chrome is now open in Kiosk Mode"
```

I know this is a very far fetched example, but it works to explain what I am trying to do. Normally, those commands would all be written without their respective escape `\` characters all over the place and less `"` around each command. I'd also have them inside of a `.scpt` file.

A solution I am aware of, is to rewrite the script using `#!/usr/bin/osascript` instead of bash and go from there, but I want to be able to blend. I have found that I can test for a script file, if it does exist to create one and append each command I need to that file and then execute the required script file from within bash, but that also defeats the purpose.

There is no way that mid-way through a file, I can swap the shell being used with the `shebang` line and then swap back after I've executed the commands necessary, is there?

Any insight would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The argument for `osascript -e` can contain newlines:

```
osascript -e 'set x to "a"
say x'
```

You can also specify multiple `-e` arguments:

```
osascript -e 'set x to "a"' -e 'say x'
```

Or if you use a heredoc, `bash` interprets three characters (`\`, `$`, and `` ` ``) between `<<END` and `END` but no characters between `<<'END'` and `END`.

```
osascript <<'END'
set x to "a"
say x
END
```

Edit:

Since osascript can operate with a heredoc (ie take input from /dev/stdin) then one can just write the script as a whole file and prepend with the correct shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript

set x to "a"
say x
```

This also allows you to save your apple script as a actual program in ~/Applications/.app using the following procedure (changing  for your script's name):

```
mkdir -p ~/Applications/<APP_NAME>.app/Contents/MacOS
touch ~/Applications/<APP_NAME>.app/Contents/MacOS/<APP_NAME>
open -A TextEdit ~/Applications/<APP_NAME>.app/Contents/MacOS/<APP_NAME>
```

Ensure that both the script file in .../MacOS/ and the  matches

Comment: Indeed you are correct. I missed the first `end tell` of the script.

Comment: Any reason you don't need the `-e` on the HEREDOC example?

Comment: @iconoclast Per the man page on osascript it is one line of script. `-e statement
           Enter one line of a script.  If -e is given, osascript will not look for a filename in the argument list.  Multiple -e options may be given to build up a multi-line
           script.  Because most scripts use characters that are special to many shell programs (for example, AppleScript uses single and double quote marks, ``('', ``)'', and
           ``*''), the statement will have to be correctly quoted and escaped to get it past the shell intact.`

Comment: Sorry @uchuugaka, but I'm failing to understand how your response answers my question.  In `-e statement Enter one line of a script` there _is_ an `-e` present.  But apart from that, is a HEREDOC treated as though it were a single line?

Comment: @iconoclast - one simple rule for this. If you can `|` pipe into a command, then you can `HEREDOC` to it, as both methods are communicating with the command via `stdin`.  This also means you can use the command as a _shebang_, e.g. `/usr/bin/osascript`. (Which is also using stdin to send input to the process). Try `echo "set Volume 2" | osascript` for a quick test.

Answer (score 35):

You can wrap the raw AppleScript in `<<EOD`... The last `EOD`, signalling the end of input, has to come at the first position in the line.

(BTW, your applescript seemed to be missing an `end tell` after `activate`....)

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript <<EOD
  tell application "Google Chrome"
      activate
  end tell
  tell application "System Events"
      key down {command}
      key down {shift}
      keystroke "f"
      key up {shift}
      key up {command}
  end tell
EOD

echo "Google Chrome is now open in Kiosk Mode"
```