# Embedding AppleScript inside a Bash -- getting Error

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash

I'm fiddling with bash for the first time and trying to get something simple to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
    while true ; do
    osascript <<EOF
        tell application "System Events"
            tell every desktop
                set picture to "/Users/bill/Desktop/bckg_changer/ARM_1885.jpg"
            end tell
        end tell
    EOF
done
```

When I execute this file from the command line, it throws:

```
Bills-iMac-4:test bill$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103638/293832) question, and the formatting and structure is similar - so not sure what is missing.

The picture changing script itself works - it's when I add the `while loop` that the end of file error is thrown.

#### Caveat

I know this script doesn't make sense - the idea was to have a continuous loop, that would revert the desktop picture to the jpg if it was subsequently changed in the System Preferences.  Obviously a poor choice of methods and resource use...  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change

```
osascript <<EOF
```

to

```
osascript <<-EOF
```

The `-` lets you indent the terminating EOF.

Comment: Adding the `<<-EOF` still throws the Error, but removing the indent as you elude to in the answer worked.

Comment: @BillArmstrong `<<-EOF` allows indenting with tabs, but not spaces.